# how to manipulate matrices element by element operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following vectors:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [0.25 0.5];
```

I'd like to obtain a 2x2 matrix c:

```
c = [1/0.25+1/0.5  2/0.25+1/0.5  

     1/0.25+2/0.5  2/0.25+2/0.5];
```

how would i achieve the matrix d based on a and b

```
d= [ 1/0.25  2/0.25
     1/0.5   2/0.5]
```

thanks

Comment: I suppose you'd want it generalized for an arbitrary number of elements in `a` and `b`? If so, could you provide a 3x3 example?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
A = repmat(a, numel(a),1);  
A/b(1) + A.'/b(2)
```

for the second part of your question, try

```
d = bsxfun(@rdivide, a, b.')
```

Comment: thanks thats perfect allows for expansion also

Comment: hi do you mind if i add an additional piece to the question

Comment: ive tried various modifications of the above code but am i little stuck as i can only modify the calculation for the first row

Comment: @mathew: See my latest edit

Comment: Hi just wondering how i would generalize the code for any square matrix?

Comment: By the way i am aware the question is a duplicate i was encouraged to rewrite the question i fully stated that the question should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate d this way:

```
d = (1./b)'*a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
c = [ a(1)/b(1)+a(1)/b(2) a(2)/b(1)+a(1)/b(2) a(1)/b(1)+a(2)/b(2) a(2)/b(1)+a(2)/b(2)];
```

Comment: I don't think what mathrew wants is this....